# Huge horizontal sortable column lists issue

Tags: usability, drag-n-drop, modal-windows, sorting, drawer

Sometimes pride doesn't let you but I decided to put that aside and ask for some extra opinions from minds like mine! Sorry for the long post, have to analyze my thoughts to explain my issue.

I have been designing an app that contains a huge multi-column list in part of the page like so:

[image]

Although it looks like it, it is not render in table, but rather in column lists so that they can be manipulated easier. The screenshot is from a 1920x1080 screen and you can see about 6 columns out of the 60 in this list. The items have to be sortable. I tried different approaches.

a) Currently as you can see in the second column, when hovering on the title 4 icons appear which are: sortable, fix column, sort data, resize column. After a lot of effort I managed to use sorting properly - mainly because of other issues, the list uses a responsive fixed header - however, dragging a list item OFF SCREEN requires you to move the mouse up and down on the side of the screen to move it to the far right.

b) I tried using an 'edit' button with a side-drawer that opens on the right and then use a netflix type sortable: either drag'n'drop element or type it's sort order in the input box. Vertically more items fit on screen and it is easier to scroll screen using a mouse with a draggable object vertically than horizontally. I hate the UX though, I mean a user could think - 'hey, the lists are right there, why not allow us to drag'n'drop the columns? This must be a stupid UI designer'

[image]

c) I tried using an edit button that opens a modal and there you have a vertical list similar to the above drawer. This isolates the view which is both good and bad; good because you can easily achieve your task but bad similar to b) above - why be able to resize/fix/sort data in current view but reorder in another view?

I've been bothered by this for far too long, that's why I am here and open to all kinds of ideas. Strangely enough, on mobile things are a lot easier. People EXPECT an action to be taken before being able to issue a sort-drag action. So it's easier to use a button to 'sort' items and sort them. I have created a similar design to another part of the app that works quite nice on mobile - on both iphone and android.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome! From the 3 above solutions, the LEAST BAD is the modal one. However I need something that is not bearable but fun and easy to use!

**Edit:** Clarifying a couple of things. The table is not a conventional table per se, as it is not rendered as table > row > cell, but rather column > table > row > cell so that each column is an individual element and is allowed to be dragged and dropped easily.

To get things out of the way, the lock fixes a column on the left (as a position:fixed element), sorting works instantly and sorts data in the rows and finally resizing resizes the column width on-the-fly.

I care about functionality on both touch and non-touch devices, but my main concern is re-ordering **columns** on desktop **using MOUSE**.

Now the problem is that dragging a whole column from the first position to the last, which can be up to 20000px away is really awkward. Moving the column on the right side of the screen to push it at last position is sluggish and needs the mouse cursor to be moving up and down to continue the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with citation from Jakob Nielsen:

> Drag-and-drop designs are often the worst offenders when it's not apparent that something can be dragged or where something can be dropped. (Or what will happen if you do drag or drop.) In contrast, simple checkboxes and command buttons usually make it painfully obvious what you can click.

**Approach A**

In my opinion, works better when there are few items to reorder or almost all of them are visible on the same screen. This for few reasons:

- You have to keep button clicked for long time and it's *annoying* (or even **not so easy**) for many users (I don't mention **users with disabilities** for whom this action **may be impossible**).
- You have to move from one side to the other of your page/screen and this may be a long path to do with mouse, you may end at your (physical) desktop border or near touchpad end (making **subsequent movements even harder**).
- If to drag an item off-screen **triggers another action** (for example to drag a column outside page will hide it) then this increases chances users will do it by mistake.

Moreover in your current design you don't have any (visible) signifier, it may not be obvious that your columns are sortable (somehow).

**Approach B**

I agree with you, even if interaction is much better than with approach A. In this case users will have a permanently visible list of items which duplicate what they already have on header row. It's a **waste of space** and absolutely overkilling for reordering (especially because you won't keep it open for your whole session).

**Approach C**

You used this on mobile applications but here it seems you're working on a desktop application (at least from screen/text size on your screenshot).

It may work well also here too but you should **also** address issues described for approach A: mouse only sorting can be annoying and/or difficult.

**Alternative Approach(es)**

You should at least follow these:

- You can complement arbitrary reordering with *holistic* **ordering schemes**. For example alphabetical, relevance or by some other attribute. These schemes are a good way to start a custom ordering from clean scenario.
- Do not forget to provide a **reset to default** option, it's especially useful when you have a large amount of columns (you can skip this if you already have a *default* ordering scheme they can select).
- Drag and drop is a very natural approach but it may not be optimal in every situation (see previous paragraphs) then you should also provide **alternative approaches**. Ordering must be possible even without mouse then don't forget to include keyboard shortcuts (for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd>).
- When using mouse you should (because of possible difficulties) provide an **alternative approach** that does **not require dragging**. It's almost everywhere universally accepted the use of two buttons: ◀ and  ▶ (or, for vertical lists, ▲ and ▼).
- Do not forget to give a **continuous feedback** while dragging and to introduce **signifiers on your draggable items** (they do not need to be visually prominent like in your example, even a subtle dot pattern or two horizontal/vertical lines may work).

Moreover do not stick to *simple lists*, if you're already changing items natural flow (left to right) to top to down then you may save space and **use a grid**. A grid will save a lot of space on your screen and it may make drag and drop easier (because more items will fit on the screen). Next image shows a (very raw!) example of what I mean with *grid layout*:

[image: Grid layout example]

In this example I'm using boxes as placeholders, they can arrange much more information (see later). Note that each row in this grid contains columns that fit one page of your view, let me abuse and call this *fixed layout*. You may have white space on both left and right sides. An alternative approach is *fluid layout* where you fit in each grid row as much column as possible, regardless how they will be displayed in your horizontal header.

Notes:

- Each *group* (of somehow related items) has a different background color. Of course it's not *mandatory* (especially because it may *fight* with your current design) but some sort of grouping may help to locate items by *affinity*. It has not to be background color, it may be border color, icon or whatever else your graphic designer will provide.
- Here we have *raw* boxes but they may convey much more information (according to your audience, of course). For example:

[image: advanced grid block example]

In this mock we have background color (for groups), icon and text to identify each item plus an (optional?) informative text (in this example the count of unique values for this column). Note that this is just box internal layout, final design *must* include a signifier for dragging but dragging should be allowed **clicking anywhere in the box**.

With grid layout you may allow reordering with buttons in all directions.

If you include ◀ and  ▶ I'd avoid (if your header layout allows this) to put them on each column because buttons will move together with your column and this will force user to *follow* them in their trip. If they are in a fixed position (let's say at right side) user may simply repeatedly click on the same button to quickly move an item. If you use an in-place approach (contrary to modal dialog approach) then you also need to introduce a *selected* header column.

Few more thoughts not directly related to column ordering:

- Consider to enable **fixed columns** too. Best option (in my opinion) is to have an arbitrary selected column that will always stick on left. If I want to compare, let's say, *timestamp* with an hypothetical *language* column I won't need to search it again and again - this will also make reordering useless in this case (this usage pattern for data analysis is pretty common, at least in my experience).
- If you have a very high number of columns then please also provide a **columns pager**. It helps to quickly scan all columns. Please do not reset it when you move to next page in your list. What's a *column pager*? If you click *next page* it simply scrolls columns to have first column (after last visible one) to be first visible one:

[image: Columns pager interaction]

Comment: Very enlightening post. Commenting on your alternative approaches. Currently there is a default scheme, in order of importance of the fields depicted - importance to people that use the application. Currently the application is using the arrows < > scheme, but as you said, you have to follow the column's trip and it is exhausting, that's why I am redesigning the whole thing. A fixed column exists but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You are right that since changing the orientation with the modal, why not think in grid form? :) I also really like the idea of 'selecting' a column and using fixed arrows, however I am not sure how I could impement this properly, meaning I already have arrows on screen for pages. Last but not least, what is a column pager?

Comment: @scooterlord adding some very simple images and notes! thanks to highlight where I've been unclear

Comment: Thanks! So, commenting again, since the application is repsonsive and the columns are resizable you can't have a 'fixed group' grid - it's a good idea to have in mind though. As for the pager, I had implemented something different. If you hover the mouse cursor on the far side of the screen for more than one second, it would scroll at 0.5sec intervals per screen width. I think I'll go with grid style after all, although I had initially thought about it and rejected it. It will be used just for template creation and IT people will be using the app, so hopefully no issues will be encountered.

Comment: @scooterlord I like temporized _auto-scroll_ idea! You can have a fixed grid layout even with responsive layout for your page (but you have to perform calculations before showing the grid to determine maximum number of columns for each row). Well, from IT people you may expect they _learn_ UI artifacts quickly...

Comment: ...well, it could be responsive if the columns weren't resizable :/ I don't think it will work in this case

Comment: @scooterlord thanks for accepting this answer but I would **wait** little bit more. UX has much less users than SO (for example) and answers may be much longer to write. Unanswered questions may catch more visits and there are **more chances you get another and better answer**! You may unaccept and wait one or two days!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused, so I need to ask some more questions:

- Since you mention mobile as a second design later, is your question
  about  mouse interaction? Do you require one design to cover mouse
  and touch devices, or are you willing to develop two different
  approaches?
- "Sortable columns" first sounded like you want to sort the table rows. But reading on, actions are `sortable, fix column, sort data, resize column`. In the first image, I only see the double-headed horizontal arrow. I assume you want to provide re-ordering of columns, fixing columns (exempting this and all cols to the left from horizontal scrolling), resizing columns, and reordering rows. Correct?
- Is your remark about dragging "OFF SCREEN" about how to remove a column from the display? If not, what result should dragging off screen have?

In general, I'd go for (a) and avoid (b) and (c), because (a) is direct manipulation and allows previewing during changes.

The most important (frequent) action is **sorting the data**, I assume, and should thus be quick. If you need sorting on a single column only, a click on the column header can cycle through ascending, descending, unsorted (shown by an icon). If the data must be sorted according to two or more columns ("srcevent first, if that's equal order according to timestamp"), you need more, of course.

If mouse-only, the standard solution to **reordering and resizing columns** is drag-and-drop. Clicking the column header (or the column border) changes the cursor, and dragging shows a continuous preview of the result.

You can try to handle **removing columns** by dragging as well: Either remove the column when the user drags it outside the table (should be announced by a change in the cursor so the user knows where to let go). Or, invent a "column storage" somewhere (the rect on the right of the column header above the vertical scrollbar?), where the user can drop the unneeded columns. To get a column back, hovering this space can show a list of draggable columns. (The fancy solution is to animate columns dropped outside the table to this place - indicating where to find them again :-)) Alternatively, use a context menu (on column header) to remove and redisplay a column (a list of checkboxes with columns).

I've not seen "**Fix Column**" so much. Excel has it separate from the column headers, but you could place this in the column header context menu if it's there.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and thorough answer, clarifying a few more things in a bit on topic start.